# Apache rewrite rule- how to prevent URL change in browser in case of POST request

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule which is as follows:

```
RewriteRule /rolFlow /a2c/allianceflow.html?pub=TCN [PT]
```

My root url is say **www.a2c.com**

**My Requirement:** When user types in www.a2c.com/rolFlow in browser he should be redirected to the URL given in the rewrite rule above but the browser URL remain unchanged i.e it should still remain www.a2c.com/rolFlow though page getting rendered is from url www.a2c.com/allianceflow.html?pub=TCN.

**The ISSUE:** When the above(www.a2c.com/rolFlow) is GET request the browser URL does not get changed as expected but in case of POST request the URL in browser is getting changed to www.a2c.com/allianceflow.html?pub=TCN.

How can I prevent URL change in browser in case of POST request?Could anyone suggest

Answer (score 1):

Is the forms response hard-coded to point to that URL?  It's not the rewrite that behaves any differently.

Comment: Yes i have a form which contains some hidden fields, the target for which I have set to /rolFlow.
So I expect that on submitting the form it should go to /rolFlow and then automatically get redirected to /allianceflow.html?pub=TCN and url in browser should remain /rolFlow.
However the browser URL is getting changed to /allianceflow.html?pub=TCN.

Comment: Yes you were right dear.It was the hardcoding in the code which was doing the change. Thanks!!!